# How do I check is product in my wishlist?

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0, wishlist, products

Can I check if a product is in my wishlist? If yes, how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Option one. Seams cleaner.

```
$productId = 1;
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($productId)
$customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
$wishlist = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist')->loadByCustomer($customerId, true);
$hasProduct = false;
foreach ($wishlist->getItemCollection() as $_item) {
    if ($_item->representProduct($product)) {
       $hasProduct = true;
       break;
    }
}
//$hasProduct tells you if the product is in the wishlist
```

//Option 2. Seams faster

```
$productId = 1;
$customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
$wishlist = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist')->loadByCustomer($customerId, true);
$collection = Mage::getModel('wishlist/item')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('wishlist_id', $wishlist->getId())
    ->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $productId);
$item = $collection->getFirstItem();
$hasProduct = !!$item->getId();
```

Comment: Option 2 worked very well, thank you Marius.

Comment: @TimHofman. Thanks for the edit.. Damn copy/paste.

Comment: @Marius no problem!

Comment: Option2: $hasProduct = (bool) $collection->count()